# How can I run this except sub-query in one single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I am using postgreSQL, I have two tables, one is user, and one is usertasks.

user has following fields : **userid, username**

usertasks has following fields: **id, taskdate, userid**

userid and id are primary keys on above tables

I want to find all users who have made less than 3 tasks in last 3 months.
I cannot use **WHERE taskdate>(last3months)** here because I need all the users, not just those who made tasks in last 3 months. (Some users might have done their tasks 6 months ago, but didn't do any task in last 3 months, so I need those users as well)

My query is this:

```
select userid
from users
EXCEPT
select userid from usertasks
where usertasks.taskdate > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months'
group by usertasks.userid having count(id) >= 3
```

**Problem:**
The above query works perfectly and returns the right result, I have also tried NOT IN , instead of EXCEPT, that works fine too, but the thing is I am getting performance issues, can this be done in one single query without using a sub query, can it be done using joins or any other method ? The use of sub-queries making it slower.

the test case is for 100 thousand users and 1 million tasks, i am searching for fastest methods..

Comment: "The fastest methods" is: add some structure to your data model, such as Primary Keys, Foreign Keys, and *maybe* indexes. After that, every appropiate (and reasonable) query would yield about the same performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `having` with a `case`.

```
Select u.user_id
from users u
left join usertask ut
on ut.user_id=u.user_id
group by u.user_id
having count(case when ut.taskdate > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months' then task_id else null end)<3 -- count of tasks in last 3 monthx < 3
```

Comment: "then user_id else null end" thats the task id, not user id, please edit that and correct, other than that, I tested your query and it works fine and giving the right result, I will post about the performance of this query soon.

Comment: @user1735921 changed to reflect your request, but as long as the task ID is not null, then the result should be the same, as the user ID must be non null to be joined in the first place. Performance wise, this is probably among the better choices, and I doubt you will have an easy time rewriting the query for better performance without changing the underlying schema .

Comment: 100k users and 1m tasks is not much, but it will not be instant no matter how you approach it. If you want it to scale well, you can look into ways of reducing the bit size of the columns used(such as pre-computing a month out of the date or using mediumint unsigned for INT ID field when you have less than 16m users), along with proper indexing

Comment: also, if you only need user_id, then you don't even need to join the 2 tables, and rather the usertask table is enough, since it already contains your user_id

Comment: Performance was great. It did the trick. I am using join, because id is not the only thing I want, so thanks for the advice though. I also need username and all those things. That was just an example.